# Centrar icono en Header de ventana modal

Tags: html5, css, bootstrap

Tengo la siguiente estructura de código HTML:

```
<div class="modal-header-success">

  <h3 class="modal-title" style="text-align: center;">
    Modal PopUp
    <button type="button" class="close panelTitleTxt glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
  </h3>
</div>
```

El cual me genera el siguiente header:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiere centrar el Icono señalado con la flecha, agradezco cualquier ayuda que puedan brindarme.

Comment: Deberias inspeccionar con el developer tools del browser que estilo tiene aplicado el boton del header y extender el style de bootstrap para cambiar como se alinea verticalmente. Eso si, nunca cambies el .css de bootstrap directamente, tiene que extender el estilo no modificar los archivos de la libreria

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pon el botón antes del título:

```
<button type="button" class="close panelTitleTxt glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-dismiss="modal"></button>
<h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
```

Te dejo un Snippet para que lo ejecutes aquí mismo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Ejemplo</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Abrir Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close panelTitleTxt glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-dismiss="modal"></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Algún texto de prueba.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No entiendo el downvote, deberían aclarar el porque.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta dada por Alan **NO** soluciona el problema, no es posible (al menos en este caso) centrar verticalmente el botón solo cambiándolo de posición. Pueden comprobarlo en su demo, mirando el inspector de Chrome y agregando bordes al botón y a su contenedor.

---

Una opción sencilla basada en el código de Bootstrap 3.3.6 para centrarlo de forma **horizontal**, sería aplicar estilo a la clase `panelTitleTxt` para eliminar el `float:right;` aplicado por bootstrap a la clase `close`: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/close.less

En ese caso puedes agregar a tu archivo de css:

```
.modal-header-success .panelTitleTxt {
  float: none;
}
```

Para centrarlo de forma **vertical**, asumiendo de nuevo que usas Bootstrap 3.3.6, puedes aplicar el siguiente estilo:

```
.modal-header-success .panelTitleTxt {
  /* Usar el mismo valor de line-height del contenedor, en este caso el h3 */
  line-height: 1.42857173;
  margin-top: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando CSS, podes acceder a la clase **close** dentro del **modal-header**, de la siguiente manera:

```
.modal-header .close {
     margin: 0 auto;
     text-align: center;
     width: 100%;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
}
```

Esto hará que tu botón quede de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En JSBIN te dejo el código: http://jsbin.com/namuxu/edit?html,output (tome el ejemplo que colocó Alan anteriormente y lo modifiqué).

Comment: En ningún lugar menciona "vertical", en ese caso, falta información en la pregunta.